# num_rows is 0 when it should be >0 for php mysqli code

Tags: php, mysqli, mysql-num-rows

My num_rows is coming back as 0, and I've tried calling it several ways, but I'm stuck.  Here is my code:

```
    $conn = new mysqli($dbserver, "dbuser", "dbpass", $dbname);

    // get the data 
    $sql = 'SELECT AT.activityName, AT.createdOn
            FROM userActivity UA, users U, activityType AT  
            WHERE U.userId = UA.userId
            and AT.activityType = UA.activityType
            and U.username = ?
            order by AT.createdOn';             
    $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
    $stmt->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $requestedUsername);
    $stmt->bind_result($activityName, $createdOn);
    $stmt->execute();

    // display the data
    $numrows = $stmt->num_rows;
    $result=array("user activity report for:  " . $requestedUsername . " with " . $numrows . " rows:");
    $result[]="Created On --- Activity Name";
    while ($stmt->fetch())
    {
        $msg = " " . $createdOn . " --- " . $activityName . " ";
        $result[] = $msg;
    }

    $stmt->close();
```

There are multiple rows found, and the fetch loop process them just fine.  Any suggestions on what will enable me to get the number of rows returned in the query?

Suggestions are much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `$stmt->store_result()` first, just before `$stmt->num_rows`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this before you call num_rows;.

`$stmt->store_result();`

Comment: For the record I did not copy your answer :) Before, your answer said something about calling `num_rows` as a method instead of a member. Then you edited it after I already answered. Don't be offended!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will fix it, but you can't `bind_results` until *after* you `execute` the query, if I'm not mistaken.

Also your while loop:

```
while ($stmt->fetch())
 {
     $msg = " " . $createdOn . " --- " . $activityName . " ";
     $result[] = $msg;
 }
```

you will lose all of the `$msg` variables with each iteration of the loop, except the last setting because you either need to do `$msg .=` or make `$msg` an array `$msg[] =`

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt->store_result();
$numrows = $stmt->num_rows;
```

Check this: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php and this
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php